# Deserialize json object with json.net with multiple lists

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the below model and I want to access the Name and Type from the class Property:

```
 public partial class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("edmx:Edmx")]
        public EdmxEdmx EdmxEdmx { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class EdmxEdmx
    {
        [JsonProperty("EntityType")]
        public List<EntityType> EntityType { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class EntityType
    {
        [JsonProperty("-Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Property")]
        public List<Property> Property { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Property
    {
        [JsonProperty("-Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("-Type")]
        public String Type { get; set; }

    }
```

I have done the below:

```
 var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(o1.ToString());
```

How do I write a loop that accesses name and type ?

Edit:
Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "edmx:Edmx": {
    "-xmlns:edmx": "http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx",
    "-Version": "4.0",
    "EntityType": [
      {
        "-BaseType": "mscrm.crmbaseentity",
        "-Name": "EntityA",
        "Property": [
          {
            "-Name": "address2_line1",
            "-Unicode": "false",
            "-Type": "Edm.String"
          },
          {
            "-Name": "territorycode",
            "-Type": "Edm.Int32"
          },
          {
            "-Name": "EntityID",
            "-Type": "Edm.Guid"
          },
          {
            "-Name": "address1_telephone1",
            "-Unicode": "false",
            "-Type": "Edm.String"
          }
        ]
      }
}
}
```

The above JSON is the o1.ToString. I use a JObject to create a JSON object from a text file.

EDIT2:

Let me try to be more precise:
I want to get this per entity: 
[image: what I want]

Comment: sorry, added the json

Comment: Okay, so you've got that much... it's not clear where you're stuck. Note that there can be multiple entity types and multiple properties per entity type... what are you trying to do with those, and what's happening at the moment?

Comment: It is not failing. I just want to access Name and Type in the class Property.

Comment: I can do this 
 string name = r.EdmxEdmx.EntityType[0].Name. This gives me the name of the Entity.
Then I need to access the Name and Type of that entity.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. The only `Type` property is within `Property`, and there are multiple properties. What value would you expect to get from the JSON you've shown?

Comment: I want to get all of them to be outputted into the console.

Comment: For example I want:
 "-Name": "territorycode",
 "-Type": "Edm.Int32"
and
  "-Name": "address2_line1",
  "-Type": "Edm.String"
outputted to the console

Comment: I have added another edit:)

Comment: So when you same "the Name and Type of that entity" you actually mean "all of the properties". It's *really* important to be as clear as you can be right from the start. So you're already showing the `Name` - if you just use `r.EdmxEdmx.EntityType[0].Property` you'll get that list of properties, and you can do what you like with them. What have you tried in terms of doing that, and what happened?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176433/discussion-between-uba2012-and-daisy-shipton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is hanging you up on this.  You have all the pieces, all you need is a nested foreach loop.

```
foreach (var entityType in r.EdmxEdmx.EntityType)
{
    foreach (var property in entityType.Property)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-Name: " + property.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("-Type: " + property.Type);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/33n7TO

Comment: My problem was that I didn't know I had to use a nested loop. Thanks Brian.